# Regex to allow groups of 7 numbers and spaces

Tags: regex

I'm looking for help with a regex.

My input field should allow only groups of up to 7 digits, and an unlimited number spaces whether at the beginning, middle, or end.

Here are a few examples of valid matches

```
Match1:
478 2635478     14587   9652

Match2 (spaces at the end):
   14     2  55586
```

I tried this regex

```
^( )*[0-9]{1,7}(( )*[0-9]{1-7})*( )*$
```

It matches when the group is 8 digits.

Comment: You can use: `^ *[0-9]{1,7}(?: +[0-9]{1,7})* *$`

Comment: You just made a typo in `{1-7}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex:

```bash
^ *[0-9]{1,7}(?: +[0-9]{1,7})* *$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rrtL3V/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `*`: Match 0 or more spaces
- `[0-9]{1,7}`: Match 1 to 7 digits
  -`(?: +[0-9]{1,7})*`: Match 1+ spaces followed by a match of 1 to 7 digits. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `*`: Match 0 or more spaces
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

An idea with one group and use of a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to separate blocks:

```
^ *(?:\d{1,7}\b *)+$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kyssXW/1) (more explanation on the right side)

`\b` will require a space or the end after each `\d{1,7}` repetition.